# SharePoint 2010 Main Summary Blog Page

Tags: 2010, xslt, content-query-web-part, blog

Is there a way to get posts to roll off on the main summary blog page? Basically we don't want posts to keep displaying after so many days (i.e. they need to roll off once they reach the set expiration date). I know the purpose of the blog is to show a running list of the posts, etc., etc. But our USERS have different thoughts about how the blog should be used. If someone could help with this I would greatly (GREATLY) appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

How good are your XSLT Skills?

I'd solve the problem by using a CQWP with a query to match your users needs in terms of content expiry and posts to show.

Then write some custom XSLT to create the HTML that you need and style as needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no XSLT skills. So I guess I'm doomed!!!

Answer (score 0):

This post describes it in practical steps of using the CQWP web part and XSLT layout for the display of the results -

[SharePoint 2010 Content Query for Blog Posts](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html)